# Permisos insuficientes en Visual Studio Code - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vscode

instale Vue.js CLI, pero mi problema es que no puedo guardar ni crear archivos, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error al guardar 'HelloWorld.vue': Permisos insuficientes. Seleccione 'Reintentar como Sudo' para volver a intentarlo como superusuario. (Adjunto la imagen)
```

[image: error que me lanza el VS Code]

Alguien me puede ayudar, incluso cuando quiero crear otro archivo me sale otro error:

```
Unable to write file '/Users/phonxy/Desktop/app/proyectosVue/appvue/src/components/sss.vue' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
```

Comment: Si estas usando Windows intenta ejecutar Visual Studio Code como administrador (click derecho>Ejecutar como administrador).

Comment: Estoy en mac compa, como sería ahí ?

Comment: Localiza donde esta VS Code y correlo con sudo en la terminal. Por default se instala en: ```/Applications/Visual Studio```, entonces en la terminal seria: ```sudo /Applications/Visual Studio```

Comment: Ya lo hice pero no funciona :/, me sigue saliendo lo mismo, como esta en la imagen

Comment: le puse esta linea
 sudo open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app

Comment: aquí tienes una respuesta en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674627/insufficient-permissions-in-vscode

Answer (score 1):

Como primera solucion te puedo dar que cambien los permisos de las carpetas donde vas a escribir, guardar modificar, etc. También es recomendable asegurarte de que el propierario es tu propio usuario ya que en mi caso siempre pertenece a root:

```
sudo chmod 777 carpeta
sudo chown usuario carpeta
```

Es mejor cambiar los permisos de los directorios ya que NO es RECOMENDABLE ejecutar como sudo el visual studio code, pero también es funcional ejecutar el VSCODE:

```
sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"
```

Cualquier cosa espero tu comentario para poder ayudarte.